# Giving Multiple Buttons an EventListener

Tags: javascript, foreach, dom-events

I'm making a website that includes carousels and buttons. When you click the buttons it moves the carousel to the left or right to see more or previous content. I made it at first by creating two functions, one for the button that goes back and one for the button that goes forward. It worked, but I realized that I needed to make it for **All** of the buttons since I had multiple carousels.

```js
var nextButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button-forward');
var backButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button-back');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-40%)';
});


backButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(10%)';
});
```

[image: bleehh]

I tried storing all the forward and backward buttons with `document.querySelectorAll` and gave them a forEach method where in it is the event listener for them. The other two carousel buttons still weren't working, I also tried making them an array to see if it would help, but it didn't change anything. In summary I want to make it where I can give the event listener to all of the pairs of buttons instead of just one. Could you guys help me? If you need a better description please tell me!

```js
var nextButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button-forward');
var backButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button-back');


nextButton.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', nextButton => {
    itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-40%)';
  })
})

backButton.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', backButton => {
    itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(10%)';
  })
})
```

Here's my HTML structure of the carousel for those who want to know:
I used the `main` element keep the parts of my carousel together, inside it is the visible_items div that only shows the items that are in it with `overflow: scroll` in CSS. Inside of that os the item_container which just contains the items. The `ion-icons` or buttons are at the top and bottom of the main element, and when you click them they make the item_container translate left or right making the items shown in the visible_items div change.

```html
    <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" class="button-back"></ion-icon>
        <main>
            <h1>Poular Shoes</h1>
            <div class="visible_items">
                <div class="item_container">
                    <div class="items">
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">

                    </div>
                    <div class="items">

                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" class="button-forward"></ion-icon>
        </main>
```

Comment: you need to look at event delegation...

Comment: What's your HTML structure?

Comment: @Unmitigated Sorry about that, i just added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure is correct, however I am afraid you are applying the transformation always to the same "itemContainer" element. This should in fact point to the element related to the button pair you assign during that iteration.

We then need to fetch all the carousels via querySelectorAll; each will have element containers and their buttons as children. In this case you have a guaranteed order and only one array to scroll through.

Example:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll(".carousels").forEach((c) => {
   const container = c.querySelector(".container")
   c.querySelector(".next")
     .addEventListener("click", 
       () => container.style...)
   c.querySelector(".back")
     .addEventListener("click",
       () => container.style...)
})
```

I would recommend that you modify your html code as follows:

```
<!-- Move this inside the carousel div -->
<ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" class="button-back"></ion-icon>
    <!-- This is not a good tag to create many carousel divs -->
    <!-- I will use something like <div class="carousel"> -->
    <main>
        <h1>Poular Shoes</h1>
        <div class="visible_items">
            <div class="item_container">
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" class="button-forward"></ion-icon>
    </main>
```

I'll leave you a snippet to start with:

```js
// get all carousels in the page
const carousels = document.body.querySelectorAll(".carousel");

// scan each carousel and assign events to children
carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
    // get item_container
    const itemContainer = carousel.querySelector(".item_container");
    // assign event to button-back
    carousel.querySelector(".button-back").addEventListener('click', () => {
        itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-40%)';
    });
    // assign event to button-forward
    carousel.querySelector(".button-forward").addEventListener('click', () => {
        itemContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(10%)';
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- Changed -->
<div class="carousel">
   <!-- Moved -->
   <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" class="button-back"></ion-icon>
   <h1>Poular Shoes</h1>
   <div class="visible_items">
      <div class="item_container">
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
         <div class="items">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" class="button-forward"></ion-icon>
   <!-- Changed -->
</div>
```

Comment: I put some information about my html structure, so if you need the info your welcome to use it! I also see what you're saying of how i'm only selection one itemContainer, but i still don't understand how you make the buttons item_containers into arrays to give them an EventListener. I will use your second idea though, it's seems really good!

Comment: Also, could you rename some stuff in your code to the html i have so i can get a better understanding?  It's alright if you don't want to.